# google maps Custom marker angular

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use google map I build custom marker by using HTML5 Canvas.
with this function.

```
   function createMarker(picture) {

 var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
 canvas.width = 40;
 canvas.height = 50;
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 context.fillStyle = "rgb(193,101,214)";
 context.beginPath();

 context.moveTo(0,0);
 context.lineTo(40,0);
 context.lineTo(40,40);
 context.lineTo(25,40);
 context.lineTo(20,50);
 context.lineTo(15,40);
 context.lineTo(0,40);
 context.fill();

 var img = new Image();
 img.src = picture;
 context.drawImage(img, 2, 2, 36, 36);
 return canvas.toDataURL();}
```

and when calling it in marker

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: location,
               map: $scope.map,
               icon:createMarker("img/cat.jpg")
           });
```

the problem is that it gives me empty icon without image like this:
[image]

how to make the image appear in icon instead of call the function createMarker("img/cat.jpg") twice before marker the icon appear like this:
[image]